# How to make the form view opened from another form view read only in odoo

Tags: odoo-8

In my module i have two models, book and room. In room i will keep room details. In book i will keep the booking details of room. I have a  many2one field in book model relating to room model. When i save the record of book, near to the many2one field a redirecting button will come. On clicking that, it will open the form view of room model. I want to make the second form view to be read only. How can i do that?. I tried to keep only read access for room model, then i can't able to save book model record. So how can i complete

```
class room(models.Model):
   _name = 'room'

   name = fields.Char('room name')


class book(models.Model):
  _name = 'book'

  name =   fields.Char('booking person')
  time = fields.Datetime('time')
  room_name = fields.Many2one('room','room name')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello First take one boolean(like temp_bool) in room object,

now in book object, when you select room then write temp_bool field as True in selected room,
now based on this boolean you can give attrs in room object like attrs="{'readonly': [('temp_bool','=','True')]}"

Comment: @Nlkunj Nakum I have done like this. The opened form view is read only. But when i select the room. it is giving error as Expected singleton: room()

Comment: can you please give me error in detail?
and as per my ruff idea you can prevent this error IF condition(if i am not wrong).

Comment: @Nlkunj Error is rectified. Thanks for helping

Comment: you are most wel come

Comment: @Nlkunj I am sorry to disturb, right now another error pop up. I have a separate menu where i can create rooms. Right now i can able to create new rooms. But not possible to edit already created one

Comment: Means, in room model now i am not able to edit room details. There also it is read only?

Comment: Can I hide the small button coming after the selection of many2one field. (A small button that is coming after selection of the many2one field )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105683/discussion-between-akhil-mathew-and-nikunj-nakum).

Comment: it's totally depends on boolean,

Comment: and you have to maintain this boolean at onchange and on create also.

Comment: i didnt get you. Can you please explain

Comment: in normal case when you create new object then you have to check this Boolean is true or not, because we only have to maintain Boolean True at time of onchange, not at create,